# file upload control which is inside gridview is not working inside update panel in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

File upload control is not working ..

File upload control is inside gridview and grid view is inside update panel .

when i am doing post back file upload control 
furesume.hasfile is givig me false if file is there also it is giving false.

please can any body help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Add your gridview as a trigger for your updatepanel

Comment: its not working again full page is posting back i need only gridview to postback

Answer (score 0):

you can't use fileupload control in your updatepanel in a partial postback. 
See my answer to 
`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15539634/uploaded-file-content-preview/15546618#15546618` question, which somehow is related to yours. I have shown there a full example. 

In short, use `ajaxfileupload`